# Maven Increase the Patch version automatically

Tags: maven, pom.xml

[I have this pom.xml file](https://github.com/Liel4494/maven-hello-world/blob/master/myapp/pom.xml),

and I'm trying to increase the Patch version (1.0.0 -> 1.0.1) automatically.

how can I do that?

[I tried this guide](https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-increment-versions-for-the-maven-build-java-project-a7596cc501c2)

But when I'm run this command: `mvn validate -DbumpPatch`

I get

```
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <version>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}</version>
```

instead of

```
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
```

thanks.

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation: https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html  so you have to call: `mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set@bump-patch`. and afterwards you need to to a `mvn versions:commit`...